# Laravel 5 - Issue with Managing assets

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

I'm trying to manage assets for Laravel 5.
I have issue with assets - I want when production and make changes, to use elixir. I follow steps from video tutorial but css changes arent' displayed.

My app.blade.php looks like that:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name - @yield('title')</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{ { elixir('css/all.css') } }">
        <script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            @yield('main')
        </div>
         @yield('footer')
    </body>
</html>
```

Gulpfile.js is:

```html
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
elixir(function(mix) {
mix.sass('app.scss');
     mix.styles([
        'vendor/normalize.css',
        'app.css'
     ], null, 'public/css');

     mix.version('public/css/all.css');
});
```

I run `gulp`. It has created folder `build/css` with all-c4717759.css and my css is there but my page doesn't change with this css.

Comment: What is actually rendered in the `link` tag?